# Openbravo ant export.database error

Tags: eclipse, ant

When i tried to export my database in openbravo (ant export.database) i got the following error , am new to this frame work please help me to resolve this issue.

Buildfile: E:\Eclipse Workspace\openbravo\build.xml

```
set.code.rev:
code.rev:
init:
core.lib:
init:
compile:
build.jar:
build:
copy.core.lib:
database.lib:
init:
compile:
build.jar:
jar:
generate.entities.quick:
init:
compile.src.gen:
   [javac] Compiling 4 source files to E:\Eclipse Workspace\openbravo\build\classes
    [copy] Copying 77 files to E:\Eclipse Workspace\openbravo\build\classes
generate.entities.quick:
    [java] 0    [main] INFO  org.openbravo.base.model.ModelProvider - Building runtime       model
    [java] 8627 [main] INFO  org.openbravo.base.gen.GenerateEntitiesTask  - Generated 553 entities
   [javac] Compiling 505 source files to E:\Eclipse Workspace\openbravo\build\classes
   [javac] Compiling 1 source file to E:\Eclipse Workspace\openbravo\build\classes

export.database:
export.database.structure:
Initializing in-memory model...
Building runtime model
Model read in-memory, generating mapping...
Dal layer initialized
Database connection: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/openbravo. User: tad
Loading data from XML files

BUILD FAILED
E:\Eclipse Workspace\openbravo\build.xml:761: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Eclipse Workspace\openbravo\src-db\database\build.xml:155:     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Total time: 15 minutes 43 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's due a the parameters of your tomcat configuration within eclipse; you need to follow the Openbravo wiki:

Open your tomcat configuration

in General Information

click on Open launch configuration link, switch to Arguments tab

add the following line at the end of VM arguments input:
 -server -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms384M -Xmx1536M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M